# How to change left (or any) margin for the verse environment

Tags: margins, memoir, verse

I'd like to make the `verse` environment's left margin about half of what it currently is so that it will show up that way throughout the document. How might this be done? Currently using XeLaTeX + `memoir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verse` environment's left margin is given by `\vleftmargin` in [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir). To reduce this by 50% use

```
\setlength{\vleftmargin}{.5\vleftmargin}
```

or set it manually to your desired length. You can also specify a width parameter as the optional argument to `verse`:

```
\begin{verse}[<width>]
  %...
\end{verse}
```

Together with these you can manipulate the entire layout (margin-wise).